# Why is exiting the Stargate inconsistent?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

I'd be surprised if this hasn't been asked before, but I couldn't find it. In the awesome TV show [**Stargate: SG-1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_SG-1), I've noticed that how one exits the Stargate is inconsistent. Several times we witness someone - usually the SG-1 team - walk through the gate normally on the Earth side, but then come tumbling out on the exit side.

In-universe, it's been stated that an object in motion maintains its velocity and momentum when traveling through the gate, so tumbling out of the game makes sense when you originally jump or leap into it (as the team often does when in danger). However, if you walk in one side, you should come walking out the other side - as is shown more than half the time.

I originally thought maybe they tumbled out the exit gate due to the ramp at SGC being higher on the event horizon then the platform on the exit gate, but we've also seen the opposite - SG1 (or someone) walks or runs through the off-world gate and comes tumbling out on the Earth side.

Note that the spin-off series - [**Stargate: Atlantis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Atlantis) - appears to be far more consistent regarding how one enters and exits the gate.

**Is this inconsistency in *SG-1* merely used for dramatic effect, or is it explained in-universe?**

Comment: from my understanding typically, the stumbling is due to poor gate connections, for example in the first few episodes i believe they come through and are covered in frost a couple times, because they hadn't finished the calculations to compensate for the spacial drift, which using a normal DHD would have been handled automaticly.

Comment: Notice that they also quietly did away with the "molecular compression" (which causes the frost Himarm noted above), and that gate travel made Daniel's allergies flare up. My money is on [Early Installment Weirdness](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarlyInstallmentWeirdness)

Comment: Daniel's allergies were toned down after his sarcophagus exposure, IIRC. which would be only consistent.

Comment: @ths he still needed glasses after the exposure wore off, his allergies should have flared up again. but they were trying to move away from bookish nerd to his Indiana Jones status

Comment: @jason the allergy issue probably had to do with the new locations, not the gate it self, no? Being sent to all those Canadian woods would flair anyone's allergies up.

Comment: Can you give some examples of when this happens?

Comment: Are you referring to incident like SG1 1:18 (Solitudes) where team members are flung out of the gate?

Comment: @Richard I'd have to go back and look. I'm about halfway thru the third season and I've noticed that probably 1/3 of the time, they walk in one side and come tumbling/rolling/flying out the other side for no reason.

Comment: Actually, the molecular decompression issue was a problem to be solved in-universe, and was given a technical explanation. I believe it had a lot to do with how they had an older version of the "phone book", and that stars had drifted over some 3,000 years, causing inconsistencies in the connection that were solved by updating the star positions in the database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most quirks of the SGC Stargate can be attributed to two things.

1. Earth knowledge of how the Gate works is incomplete and immature.
2. Earth technology and implementation of the Gate normal dialing computer.

We learn plenty of times that the SGC bypasses many of the safety and routine protocols that the DHD has,  ignoring many of the feedback codes of the Gate, and often force the connection even when they shouldn't.

Atlantis on the other hand has a better understanding of the gate,  has access to a more advance gate,  and use the existing gate control system of the city ship.

Reason 3 is equal parts dramatic effect,  growing pains of production and lore, and budget.

Comment: I'm up to season five with no explanation, so I have a feeling there is no in-universe reason. Accepted!

Answer (score 7):

Occasionally, it's something weird with the gates.

The general cause is explained, offhandedly, in season five, episode five.

After an unexpected rough exit, Carter mentions that "The margin of error in calculating planetary shift used to cause the rough ride but we fixed it."

See [the episode's page on the wikia](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Sky) for more of the dialogue.

(Before I went looking, I actually remembered that explanation coming from a different episode, so it may have been explained more than once)